# Collect from stream into a multimap

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, guava

I have a phrase and I'm splitting on white space and creating a map that would hold the word and the index position of the word.

I worked fine. But the problem is when the phrases contained duplicate words. So I wanted to use  `com.google.common.collect.Multimap` in [*Google Guava*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava).

Is there a way to generate the Multimap using the below stream's collector?

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(phrase.split("\\s+")));
Map<String, Integer> tokenMap = IntStream.range(0, words.size())
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(words::get, i -> i));
```

Comment: Technically this uses collector too: `Multimaps.index(IntStream.range(0, words.size()).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()), words::get)`

Comment: Using `toMap`: `Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), words::get)` and feed the `result` to `Multimaps.invertFrom(Multimaps.forMap(result), MultimapBuilder.hashKeys().arrayListValues().build())`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use this:

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList("a b c d e a b c".split("\\s+"));
Multimap<String, Integer> tokenMap = IntStream.range(0, words.size()).boxed()
        .collect(ArrayListMultimap::create, (m, i) -> m.put(words.get(i), i), Multimap::putAll);
```

The result will be:

```
{a=[0, 5], b=[1, 6], c=[2, 7], d=[3], e=[4]}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Stream.collect()` is a very general API, so there's no particular reason why one could not collect to a `Multimap`.  But none of the variants of `Collectors.toMap()` can support that because a `com.google.common.collect.Multimap` is not a `java.util.Map`.

I'm not aware of an existing `Collector` implementation that does that job, but it should certainly be possible to write one by directly implementing `Collector`.

Comment: No need to implement your own collector, just call [`Collector.of(ArrayListMultimap::create, (m, i) -> m.put(words.get(i), i), (a, b) -> { a.addAll(b); return a; })`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-)